# Should I use MeteorJS for a Public Facing App?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a lot of experience with the LAMP stack. I’m about to build out a new site that will be basically a directory, profiles, subscriptions, q&a etc etc. All of it needs to be indexed by Google. I’ve spent the last couple of weeks learning Meteor + React and I’m absolutely in love. It seems like I’d be able to create this new site really quickly with it.

I'm concerned about the initial load and the SEO concerns though. I see there are some workarounds with other packages to make indexing better, but will load time always be an issue?

I don't mind if there are workarounds, I would just hate to build out this large site using meteor just to find out that the initial load will always be slow. Which would wreck conversions (and SEO at the same time). Am I trying to fit a square peg in a round hole?

Comment: You can render a view (initially) in react server side, that waythe data is there and seo friendly

Comment: The answer can depend on what template/router libs you end up going for. Implementing SSR with React + React Router makes things a little easier, though I just solved this very issue in a Blaze/FlowRouter stack using a combination of `tomwasd:flow-router-seo` package  and `prerender.io` service